# Flask redirect -> Error 302 & render_template -> nothing happens

Tags: flask

I'm trying to create a login page, after a user writes his email & password a POST request is sent to Flask, and after checking if password & email match, Flask is supposed to redirect the user toward his account, or the home page, however neither render_template nor redirect seem to work:

Flask:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":    
        x = request.json
        email = x['email']
        password = x['password']
        print("email: "+email)
        print("password: "+password)
        if(check_user(email, password)):
            print("tries to redirect")
            #return redirect(url_for('account'))
            return render_template("pages/accounts/account.html")
        else:
            print("Connection failed")
            #return redirect(url_for('home', title_message="Error", body_message="Incorrect username or password"))
            return render_template("pages/home.html", title_message="Error", body_message="Incorrect username or password")
    return render_template("pages/accounts/login.html")
```

When using render_template, the terminal writes:

```
email: --------@gmail.com
password: hbgvytF657GYIUBh
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2021 18:02:50] "GET /login?email=--------%40gmail.com&password=hbgvytF657GYIUBh HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Connected
tries to redirect
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2021 18:02:51] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2021 18:02:51] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

When I use redirect instead, I get:

```
email: --------@gmail.com
password: hbgvytF657GYIUBh
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2021 18:08:18] "GET /login?email=--------%40gmail.com&password=hbgvytF657GYIUBh HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Connected
tries to redirect
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2021 18:08:19] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2021 18:08:19] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But in both cases I'm back at the login page after submitting the form, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have the `home` or `account` view functions, which you pass to `redirect(url_for( ))`

Comment: Isn't that how they should be written ?
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("pages/home.html")

@app.route('/account')
def account():
    return render_template("pages/accounts/account.html")

Comment: That's how it is written. If you are to use `redirect()` then you should have `return redirect(url_for('home'))`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I correctly implemented 'redirect' in the code https://wtools.io/paste-code/b4TZ; but I am still redirected to the same page, with code 302